# VB.net: overwrite everything in a text file

Tags: vb.net

in my VB.net Application id like to overwrite and add new content of a text file 
What Code do I need to use?
Thanks

Comment: You could start looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2). There's a lot of piece missing. What type of file, what type of data, what's the new content, ...

Comment: as i said, a .txt file, and normal strings as data (plain text)

Comment: You can [ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) of the file. Do the changes from the resulting string. Then [WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_) back to the file.

Comment: Check out File.Open(String, FileMode) Then check FileMode. It looks like the Truncate field of FileMode might do what you want.

Comment: Do some research on reading and writing text files in VB.NET.  There's loads of information around.  When you open a file for writing, the only options are overwriting or appending so there's no great mystery to how to overwrite.  It's the default in most cases. You should ALWAYS be looking for existing information first and then ask here if you aren't able to make what you've learned work. SO is not a place to ask a question as the first option.

Comment: You can make use of the `System.io.file`  class

Answer (score 4):

Read (ie: load) everything in the TXT file into your program.

```
Dim sFullPathToFile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Sample.txt"

Dim sAllText As String = ""
Using xStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sFullPathToFile)
    sAllText = xStreamReader.ReadToEnd
End Using
Dim arNames As String() = Split(sAllText, vbCrLf)

'Just for fun, display the found entries in a ListBox
For iNum As Integer = 0 To UBound(arNames)
    If arNames(iNum) > "" Then lstPeople.Items.Add(arNames(iNum))
Next iNum
```

Because you wanted to overwrite everything in the file, we now use StreamWriter (not a StreamReader like before).

```
'Use the True to indicate it is to be appended to existing file
'Or use False to open the file in Overwrite mode
Dim xStreamWRITER As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(sFullPathToFile, False)

'Use the carriage return character or else each entry is on the same line
xStreamWRITER.Write("I have overwritten everything!" & vbCrLf)
xStreamWRITER.Close()
```